# I integrate an adminLTE template in Angular 8. the first time when I launch the server the program works correctly after it gives this error

Tags: angular8, adminlte

ERROR in src/assets/plugins/filterizr/FilterContainer.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/angular_workspace/templateAngular/src/assets/plugins/filterizr/FilterizrOptions/defaultOptions
"' has no exported member 'RawOptionsCallbacks'.

1 import { RawOptionsCallbacks } from './FilterizrOptions/defaultOptions';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/assets/plugins/filterizr/FilterItems.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/angular_workspace/templateAngular/src/assets/plugins/filterizr/ActiveFilter"' has no exported member 'Filte
r'.

1 import { Filter } from './ActiveFilter';
           ~~~~~~
src/assets/plugins/filterizr/Filterizr.d.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/angular_workspace/templateAngular/src/assets/plugins/filterizr/ActiveFilter"' has no exported member 'Filter'
.

4 import { Filter } from './ActiveFilter';
           ~~~~~~
src/assets/plugins/filterizr/Filterizr.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/angular_workspace/templateAngular/src/assets/plugins/filterizr/FilterizrOptions/defaultOptions"' has no expor
ted member 'RawOptions'.

5 import { RawOptions } from './FilterizrOptions/defaultOptions';
           ~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same error when i tried to launch the server.
Replace imports in these classes:

**"Filterizr.d.ts" in plugins/filterizr** 
Replace these imports:

```
import { Filter } from './ActiveFilter'; 
import { RawOptions } from './FilterizrOptions/defaultOptions';
```

For these:

```
import { Filter } from './types/index'; 
import { RawOptions } from './types/interfaces';
```

**"FilterContainer.d.ts" in plugins/filterizr:** 
Replace this import:

```
import { RawOptionsCallbacks } from './FilterizrOptions/defaultOptions';
```

for:

```
import { RawOptionsCallbacks } from './types/interfaces';
```

**"FilterItems.d.ts" in plugins/filterizr:** 
Replace this import:

```
import { Filter } from './ActiveFilter';
```

for

```
import { Filter } from './types';
```

Comment: By the way, i'm using adminLTE v3.0.1

Comment: i want to delete folder Filterizr in assets/plugin. Problem solved! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: Thanks! FYI if for whatever reason, someone is trying to implement this in a asp.net webforms solutions in VS2019 this above solution works too

Comment: Thank you, It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the Filterizr folder from your plugins folder in assets
its useless for me and works

Answer (score 0):

Filterizr plugin folder also contains the source code. Just keep the .js files and remove everything else inside /plugins/Filterizr folder. Remove .d.ts files. Problem solved.